# Yii1 Remove initial Search

Tags: gridview, yii, grid, yii1.x

I'm having problems trying to display a list of elements on `CGridView`,I have a table with a boolean field `is_active` who had us `0` default value, so when I want to display this table on `CGridView` it show just the rows with 0 on is_active field and add `0` on search input by default.

I add this line to search function `$criteria->compare('is_active',$this->is_active,false);` but stil not working

This is my search function

```
public function search()
{

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('title',$this->title);
    $criteria->compare('description',$this->description);
    $criteria->compare('is_active',$this->is_active,false);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

This is my CGridView

```
...
{
  'header' : 'Activated',
  'filter' : CHtml.activeTextField( model, 'is_active' ),
  'value' : '$data->is_active ? "Oui" : "Non" '
}
...
```

This what I got

[image]

But wat I want is to show all table's elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`unsetAttributes()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#unsetAttributes-detail) to reset default values detected from database schema:

```
$model = new MyModel('search');
$model->unsetAttributes();
if (isset($_GET['MyModel'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_GET['MyModel'];
}
$dataProvider = $model->search();
```